# Angular JS and FXM

Tags: fxm

We have a single page application (Angular JS). We would like to bring it to the FXM, connection with beacon is successful, everything looks good. Until I open the the web site in FXM experience editor, and it is blank. I have read on the official web site about the limitations that FXM does not support.

> Dynamic HTML generated by Document Object Model (DOM) or modified by
>   JavaScript.

Does anyone know a workaround maybe for this? How can I have my Angular Application

Comment: I think you are going to get hammered by "too broad" for this question. Try narrowing the scope down a bit; explain what you have done so far and where you've come to a halt.

Comment: Okay first of all I set up an FXM external web site. Go to Sitecore LaunchPad>Federated Experience Manager>Add External Web site. Copy the beacon to my AngularJS Web Application(Single Page Application). Save everything and go ahead and click "Open Site in Experience Editor". Once The FXM loads up it is a blank screen. I have read on the web site that FXM does not support Dynamic HTML generated by DOM or modified by JS. So I was wondering is there is a workaround this?

Comment: Agreed, this is still a pretty broad question. Do you have an error that occurs in JavaScript? Or does everything load without errors, but nothing happens? Which browser, all of them? And does this happen just in the FXM editor? or does it also happen on the published site? Have you tried just that you can get any JavaScript running through FXM, as that itself can be tricky.

Comment: I am also in a exact situation. Looking for some guidance.

Comment: Jarmo is correct. Problem is that you are trying to open page in Experience Editor. Try to open published website in another browser window and best in incognito/private mode. Another question could be whether you are not mixing http and https. This is also not supported by FXM

Comment: @JarmoJarvi are domains both on http or https?

Comment: @Tony Usually prefer both of these to be set on https. But should work between http. The limitation is that if the main domain is https, then it can't call fxm from an http domain.

Comment: @SaadAhmedKhan I wanted to share with you an article that illustrates integration of AngularJS with Sitecore, not FXM. But It might help.

https://mysitecore.blog/2017/06/27/experience-editor-with-angular-js-integration/